# Could not get unknown property 'resDir' for task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried to build my existing code with latest build.gradle (4.1) and android plugin (3.0) but it always give me following error

**Error:Could not get unknown property 'resDir' for task ':6-MyApp:processReleaseResources' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.**

My App gradle file looks like

```
   sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }

            androidTest {
                //ignoreFailures = true
                manifest.srcFile 'tests/AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
                res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }


            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }  

deploy {
    resourceCompressionLevel rootProject.ext.compressLevel
    exportApk rootProject.ext.exportApk
    exportMapping rootProject.ext.exportMapping
    outputDir rootProject.ext.outputDir
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am also facing same issue